# How to serve Gziped webpack bundles from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-s3, gzip, webpack

I need to serve a webpack bundle (and derived assets) from AWS S3, and I want to serve those files Gziped if the browser supports it. S3 doesn't Gzip content on-the-fly, so you have to upload both uncompressed and compressed versions of your assets and implement the logic to select the corresponding version from client side.

Now, when I serve the html page from my server, I can choose to load the `main.bundle.js` file or its compressed version `main.bundle.js.gz`, depending on the `Accept-encoding` header in the request.

The problem is that webpack doesn't know anything about the Gziped version of my assets, so it keeps loading the rest of the bundle chunks with their uncompressed files.

Is there a way to tell webpack to load the bundle chunks and other files appending a suffix to their paths (in this case `.gz`)?

The only solution I can think of is to generate two separate bundles, one for uncompressed files and the other one for the gziped ones, with different `publicPath` to differentiate them. But I think it might be an overkill, as the two bundles would be practically identical.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there browsers that don't natively support gzip that anyone cares about?  I gzip my content, save *without* .gz extension, set `Content-Encoding: gzip` and... done.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that's a good point, but given that I have no idea which browsers will be requesting our site, and my instructions are that we must give support to all browsers, I have to serve the site both compressed and uncompressed

Comment: @iuri you shouldn't be concerned with browser support. It is practically universal unless you step back into 90's era browsers which means that your deployed app probably wouldn't function correctly anyway. There are some very edge case 'clients' like crawlers, bots, and maybe some legacy server tools that might be affected, but again those would be incredibly old and are unlikely to matter to your target user base.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable CloudFront on the S3 bucket, they recently *(12/17)* just added the option to gzip. See: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-gzip-compression-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/